# bouncycastle How to determine first byte (recovery ID) for ECDSA signatures

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm using BouncyCastle to sign transactions for the EOS blockchain. Similar to Bitcoin signatures, the signature needs to have a "recovery ID" as the 1st bytes. My code looks as follows:

```cs
var curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");
var domain = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H);

var p = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(privateKey);

var keyParameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(
                        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1,privateKey),
                        domain);

ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA");

signer.Init(true, keyParameters);
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
var signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
```

This seems to work as expected but I'm unable to get the recovery ID.

Here's an example of how another library does this.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc/blob/a806b93fbbccec8d38c0c02998d204ff2040a6ae/src/ecdsa.js#L199

Can someone explain how I can do that same using BouncyCastle please?

This was another post that seemed helpful, but wasn't specific to how to do this with BouncyCastle https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/how-to-determine-first-byte-recovery-id-for-signatures-message-signing

Comment: A duplicate ? [Recreate X and Y of Elliptic curve from public key byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48929222/1820553)

Comment: Isn't the recovery of a public key from a signature different from that?

Comment: SEC 1 section 4.1.6 seems more involved than just creation from r & s in byte arrays.

Comment: I don't think that BouncyCastle has a built-in functionality to calculate the recovery id. For this you will need special libraries, e.g. for C# [Cryptography.ECDSA](https://github.com/Chainers/Cryptography.ECDSA/blob/master/Sources/Cryptography.ECDSA/Secp256k1Manager.cs#L257) (not tested). For testing, note the [low probability](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v/38909#comment81790_38909) for 2 and 3 (respectively 29 and 30).

Comment: It is v that I'm trying to calculate I believe. This thread has a pretty detailed breakdown https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v/38909#38909

Comment: Well, if you want to implement the logic for the calculation yourself, you can do that. I thought maybe, it is easier to use an existing implementation.

Comment: lol .. sorry I have not desire to write the calc myself. I am looking to leverage something like Cryptography.ECDSA  .. I missed your message earlier. I'll check that out and see if it does the trick for me, thank you.

Comment: This was the best answer I could find - https://www.py4u.net/discuss/765275